# Google Analytics Plugin Not Reporting Users in Dashboard

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, google-analytics, cordova-plugins

I am trying to add Google Analytics to my app. I am using Dan Wilson's Google Analytics plugin. I am not getting any errors but my Google Analytics Dashboard is not Updating at all. Where am i wrong,

```
var googleanalyticsApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {    
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);     
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
if(window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}

if(typeof analytics !== undefined) {                
            analytics.startTrackerWithId("UA-872489XX-1");
            console.log("Analytics Initialized");
        } else {
            console.log("Google Analytics Unavailable");
        }
  });
});

googleanalyticsApp.controller('ExampleController', function($scope,$cordovaGoogleAnalytics) {
function _waitForAnalytics(){

      if(typeof analytics !== 'undefined'){         
       analytics.startTrackerWithId("UA-872489XX-1");
       analytics.trackView('APP first screen');          
       console.log("Analytics in Controller");
      }

      else{

      setTimeout(function(){

      _waitForAnalytics();

      },250);

      }
      };

  _waitForAnalytics();
```

I have initialized the Google Analytics in both Device Ready and Controller.
Console.log states as:
 [image: Console]

But my Dashboard is not updating at all

[image: Dashboard]

Kindly, help me out.

Comment: correct me if I'm missing some code, but I don't see any call to `trackView`, `trackEvent` or any other tracking function included in the plugin. So.. what do you expect to be tracked exactly? Also note, that Google Analytics might take several hours to show the actual results, you might try to use the realtime view though, but to be a 100% sure if it's working or not give it a few hours to update (would suggest to have another look now and if nothing is shown, add some tracking calls)!

Comment: Hi @OClyde, i have already added TrackView( Also shown it in the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dashboard is pointing at Nov 14 - Nov 14. Change this to the current day, it defaults to the previous day.

It can take up to 24 hours for data to appear in Analytics console. Also why do you have different naming conventions when calling analytics functions? You can change 'analytics' to $cordovaGoogleAnalytics in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set trakid In app.js platform ready like following -

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  if(typeof analytics !== undefined) {                
            analytics.startTrackerWithId("UA-872489XX-1"); // set your trakId
            console.log("Analytics Initialized");
        } else {
            console.log("Google Analytics Unavailable");
        }
  });
})
```

If above won't work use following -

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      if(window.ga != undefined) {
                      window.ga.startTrackerWithId("UA-872489XX-1");
                  } else {
                      console.log("Google Analytics Unavailable");
                  }
    })
```

Then in each controller just set view like following -

```
googleanalyticsApp.controller('ExampleController', function($scope,$cordovaGoogleAnalytics) {
   // Here no need to wait to load analytics as already loaded
   analytics.trackView('APP first screen');          

})
```